# Deleting binary rows

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

if im using replicating tetris using an unsigned long's bits to represent and 8 by 8 grid of blocks, what bitwise operations can I do to find rows of 1's (filled rows), and delete them?

I can find a row using a loop and delete the *last* row with a simply bitshift, yet not only is my method ineffective the bitshift will only work on the last row, as it will delete other rows as well when used above.

Comment: *using an unsigned long's bits*. Don't just describe code in words. Please show the code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The size of `unsigned long` is implementation-specific.  Please be more precise about your data size, and show the code for what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dealing with a single 64-bit unsigned integer for your 8x8 bits, let's start with using the correct data type: `uint64_t`

Now, let's adopt a convention of which bits are "above", because you have not been specific about that.  I'll assume that higher-order bits represent higher rows, and so removing a row will involve shifting bits to the right.

Finally, I'll assume that the "bottom" is row 0, and the "top" is row 7.  That means for example you could do something like get a mask for the bits corresponding to a single row as follows:

```
uint64_t row_mask = (uint64_t)0xff << row * 8;
```

I'm sure you can see how this mask can be used to detect all ones.  You just have to bitwise-AND with your state and check the result is the mask itself.  Here's a pretty simple approach:

```
int row = 0;
while (row < 8) {
    uint64_t row_mask = (uint64_t)0xff << row * 8;
    if ((state & row_mask) == row_mask) {
        remove_row(&state, row);
    } else {
        ++row;
    }
}
```

Now we've established an actual specification for how a row is addressed, let's imagine you are now going delete row 3.  To do this, you must shift all rows above row 3 to the right, and leave rows 0-2 unchanged.

Note that you can use a trick to obtain a mask for the bits in every row underneath a specific row as follows:

```
uint64_t rows_below_mask = ((uint64_t)1 << row * 8) - 1;
```

This works by shifting a 1 to the last bit in the current row, then subtracting 1, which will clear that bit and set all bits to the right.

You can use that same value to derive a mask for all rows *above* the current row.  Just invert it, and then shift left so that we ignore the current row:

```
uint64_t rows_above_mask = ~rows_below_mask << 8;
```

That's pretty much all you need...  Just mask off the parts, shift and combine:

```
void remove_row(uint64_t *state, int row)
{
    uint64_t rows_below_mask = ((uint64_t)1 << row * 8) - 1;
    uint64_t rows_above_mask = ~rows_below_mask << 8;
    *state = (*state & rows_below_mask) | (*state & rows_above_mask) >> 8;
}
```

If you wish to chain multiple values together, assuming you have more than 8 rows in your Tetris game, more logic is required for dealing with selecting the right row and carrying data.  That's an exercise for you to consider doing yourself.